# How to host nodeJS project to firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using node, express and more other dependencies for the project. I wonder how to host this project on firebase. My project will have controller, view , and any other folders to make the project possible.It already has view  engine like pug/handlebars.

Tutorials online only show how to host firebase with single index.html in public folder. How am I suppose to host my project with all other folders? I know how to use firebase in nodeJS, but how to host the project on firebase? How firebase will access the server file(either app/index.js)? Where should I put all these folders?

Hopefully I am not asking to much. If my question isn't clear, please let me know so that I can make clarification.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You're in luck. Firebase just this week released a [video that walks step-by-step through setting up an Node.js/Express app on Firebase Hosting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8).

This has only been possible since the integration of Cloud Functions with Firebase Hosting, which was released at I/O 2017. Most tutorials likely are from before that time, when there was no way to run server-side code on Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Nice! I will definitely check the link.

Comment: Hi suppose my nodejs app is connected to mongo db locally how will this work

Comment: Should I move my all module files under functions folder?

Comment: The node modules that are used by the server-side code that runs in Cloud Functions will need to be in the `node_modules` directory under the `functions` folder indeed. The node modules that are used in the front-end code, will need to be in the `node_modules` directory that the bundler uses for the front-end.

Comment: Most of the thing used in the video are old/deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by firebase cloud function.
Deployment auth is handled by the Firebase CLI, so getting a hello world up and running is literally:

```
firebase init functions
firebase deploy
```

A simple hello world function

```
functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send(“Hello from Firebase!”);
});
```

**Note: You can use express with firebase function.**

For more follow documentation link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions